помогите с ошибкой. почему-то выдаёт мне invalid syntax в строке с elif на e что нужно изменить?
chislo = int(input("введите число от 5 до 10"))
if chislo >= 5 and chislo <= 10:
    print("спасибо")
else:
    while chislo < 5 or chislo > 10:
        print("неверно")
        if chislo < 5:
            print("число слишком маленькое")
            chislo = int(input("введите число от 5 до 10")
        elif chislo > 10:
            print("число слишком большое")
            chislo = int(input("введите число от 5 до 10")
    print("спасибо")


В строке выше не закрыта скобка

Не закрыта скобка:
chislo = int(input("введите число от 5 до 10")
            ^     ^                          ^^? 

и вторая строка в elif тоже не закрыта скобка, должно быть так:
chislo = int(input("введите число от 5 до 10"))
            ^     ^                          ^^

